# Настройка deploy через git

Tags: linux, git, администрирование, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь настроить деплой по этому гайду: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps

Создал git хук post-receive со следующим содержимым:

```
#!bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/site.ru --git-dir=/var/repo/site.ru.git checkout -f
```

После успешного git push выводится такая ошибка:

```
Push failed: remote: error: cannot run hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить ту же команду, залогинившись по ssh.

Comment: Руками команда выполняется. Пересоздал Пустой репозиторий и пересоздал хук - все заработало.

Comment: Плохой способ деплоя. Хотя сам его использую из-за простоты. Проблема начинается, когда, например, через веб-интерфейс WordPress заливаешь файл в блог, а потом пытаешься сделать коммит.  
У залитого файла владелец www-data, а у всей директории www должен быть владелец git.

Comment: Www-data можно добавить в группу к git'у. Способ дрянь. Неспроста ни слова про пользователей в гайде. Если уж читать гайды, то Linode'овские.